How is Amazon extracting product relevant terms from reviews?
In the first picture, terms like ['Quality', 'Value', 'Taste', 'Health benefits', 'Freshness', 'Ingredients', 'Seal'] can be seen.
The reviews in the 1st picture are for toothpaste. Terms like "effect on skin" are not applicable to toothpaste but would be relevant for something like facewash. I assumed that Amazon might maintain a fixed list of terms per product category and run their model to find matching reviews for each term. However, for niche/exotic products in a category across wide range of prices, some tags that are available for one product could not be available for another. This suggests that the terms are being extracted from the reviews themselves by one model, with another model finding related claims with matching phrases. So, there is no fixed number or list of terms per product, but extraction is being done. I could be wrong. Please shed some light on this. The terms do no have fixed word count as well. This could also be done with Tf-Idf or topic-extraction, for all I know, but the extracted topics were relevant to the product.

How do you ensure that relevancy for the product in question?
Can this extraction of terms be done category wise, I mean, for all toothpastes, instead of just dabur read toothpaste?
What pre-trained models can I start with (and fine-tune if required) to find such topics from reviews?

Here are the two images of reviews for two products on Amazon.

and

